# Is there any way that when importing something random a can stop it from picking the same item twice?

Tags: python, random

Can someone help me and tell me if there is any way I can stop random functions from picking the same item twice?

For example, say this is my code:

```
import random

numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
for i in range(5):
    print(random.choice(numbers))
```

Is there any way that I can stop it from picking the same item twice?

Comment: A general solution to the "random but no duplicates" problem is to put all the possible options to pick from into an array/list/whatever and then shuffle the container.  That puts the items in a random order with no duplicates.  Take as many items as you need from the front (or end) of the array.  Many languages have a `shuffle` method built in or else use the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the element that got picked from the list.

Answer (score 0):

this will check for previous output:

```
import random
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
b=[]
for i in range(5):
    k=(random.choice(numbers))
    if not k in (b):
        print(k)
        b.append(k)
```

Comment: i'll try this for myself